# animating html elements - flexslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexslider

How do i animate html elements on each slide of flexslider after the animations of slides. Searched the internet for hours. Could not find any tutorial or something that can help.  Couldsomeone show me and example of how to do it. [Link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YvsVp/3/)

**html**

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
          <div><h1>heading</h1></div>
          <div><h2>heading</h2></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  });

$("div h1").fadeIn(3000);
$("div h2").animate({left:'250px'});
```

Comment: Elaborate a little bit more on what it is that your asking

Comment: @MoisesHidalgo Please excuse me for my bad English. Its like this.. After the first slide slide-in, The h1, h2, h3 or any other html tags on this slide should be animated seperatly (lets say fadein) . After the animations of those html attributes the slide slide-out  and next slide sliode-in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the callback functions provided by flexslider.

Callback functions:

```
start: function(){} //Fires when the slider loads the first slide
before: function(){} //Fires asynchronously with each slider animation
after: function(){} //Fires after each slider animation completes
```

You can refer this doc for more information on the available callback functions : http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Now I've updated the fiddle with a solution using the fade in possibility.

Below are the changes made to the code and here is the [updated fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/daltonpereira/YvsVp/33/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <div>
            <h1>heading</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>heading</h2>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <div>
            <h1>heading</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>heading</h2>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <div>
            <h1>heading</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>heading</h2>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <div>
            <h1>heading</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>heading</h2>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
  $("div h1").css('display', 'none'); //hide h1
  $("div h2").css('display', 'none'); //hide h2
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
  animation: "slide",
  start: function () {

      $("div h1").fadeIn(1000);
      $("div h2").fadeIn(1000);

  },
  after: function () {

      $("div h1").fadeIn(1000);
      $("div h2").fadeIn(1000);

  },
  before: function () {

      $("div h1").css('display', 'none');
      $("div h2").css('display', 'none');

  }
 });
```

I hope this has solved your problem :). Happy coding!

Comment: You're Welcome Sam :)